# UIView disappears after Typing into UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm trying to bind the UIView to the keyboard, it works fine, but when I type something in one UITextField the UIView goes to the bottom and disappears and is not even visible when the keyboard is hidden.

Here's my binding keyboard function:

```
func bindToKeyboard() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
        self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Usage in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
nextBackView.bindToKeyboard()
```

EDIT LOOK ANSWER FROM A PERSON:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `UIScrollView`, rather than a `UIView`. A scrollView will have a `contentView`, which is nothing but a `UIView`.
To this `UIView`(I would rather say a contentView) you add your textfields.

This is how it would look like in Storyboard with Constraints.

[image]

UIScrollView top and bottom space align with top and bottom layout guide. Rest of the constraints are straight forward.

In the below code, we check if the keyboard is already opened or not. If edgeinsets are zero i.e the bottom content inset is zero it means keyboard is going to open. Here we make sure the inset from the bottom will now change to for example 280.0 i.e contentview is pushed 280 points towards the top edge.

When the keyboard is closed we move `contentInset.bottom` back to 0 points from bottom of the content view,

```
func bindToKeyboard() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

//Set default to zero, when keyboard opens it changes to a non zero value. When keyboard closes it is set back to the correct value.
var scrollContentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue


    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

        if self.scrollContentInset.bottom == 0 {
            let adjustmentHeight = (endingFrame.height + 20) * (1)
            self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustmentHeight
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustmentHeight

        } else{
            let adjustmentHeight = (endingFrame.height + 20) * (-1)
            self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustmentHeight
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustmentHeight
        }

        self.scrollContentInset = self.scrollView.contentInset


    }, completion: nil)
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

The iOS `keyboardWillChange:` is called multiple times. So the keyboard logic is slightly changed here. Before the Keyboard opens, the Y is height of the UIScreen, when the keyboard is opened the Y moves up towards it's orientation(top left corner is 0,0). This helps to detect the keyboard is opening.

When the keyboard closes , sometimes because of the softkeyboard (`cmd + K`)or by return key, the height of the keyboard is different is those cases. The endframe has height of 54 points in case of (`cmd + K`) while startFrame has height of 355.0. As the keyboard was opened with height of 355.0 , it should offset by same amount. So I am using here the maximum height of startFrame as well as EndFrame.

In case the keyboard is opened in softkeyboard mode, the Y of `startFrame` and `endFrame` will be same, so in that case contentInset is not modified.

I hope this helps to answer the keyboard issue.

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let startFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue



    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

        if startFrame.minY > endingFrame.minY {
            /*
             *Keyboard opening
            */
            let adjustmentHeight = CGFloat.maximum(startFrame.height, endingFrame.height)
            self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom = adjustmentHeight
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = adjustmentHeight
        } else if startFrame.minY < endingFrame.minY{
            /*
             *Keyboard Closing
             */
            let adjustmentHeight =  CGFloat.maximum(endingFrame.height, startFrame.height) * (-1)
            self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustmentHeight
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustmentHeight
        }



    }, completion: nil)
}
```

One more thing which I found here is that in landscape mode (`landscapeRight`), the startframe height was 277.0 while endFrame height was 209.0. and when we minimize the keyboard it was with 209. This happens when device was in potrait mode and then you opened the keyboard in landsacpe right mode.

So you might want the adjustment height when keyboard opens to be the endFrameheight

```
if startFrame.minY > endingFrame.minY {

    let adjustmentHeight =  endingFrame.height
.........
}
```

Comment: Why you add 20 to the endingframe.height?

Comment: Only works on the first time clicking on the textFields after that it doesn't work when i resignfirstresponder

Comment: check question now please

Comment: @swiftixcode10 you can check the updated code, see if you get any issues.